# Accordion gridview data

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a "Accordion" in my form which is used to display a grid inside. In the page load i want to display a empty "Accordion" without grid like this..
[image]

2. After filling the form fields such as "name","department","Accordion heading" when the user click the "ADD" button it should check the dropdownlist field "Accordion heading".
3. if the user choose one then the values should added under the Accordion heading "one".
   and the data should add according to the dropdownlist selected index change of an item.

[image]

Any help?

Comment: What u have tried so far..

Comment: i tried this by using ajax-accordion-control..in the page load its working fine, when i choose any options in the dropdown, the whole accordion open its all panes...

Comment: Then u might missing a proper handler

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void DisgridBind()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;
        dt.Columns.Add("disc_points");
        dt.Columns.Add("txtchk");
        dt.Columns.Add("action_point");
        dt.Columns.Add("target_date");
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        gv_discpoint.DataSource = dt;
        gv_discpoint.DataBind();
     }
```

Add one Empty datattable like above format i you have empty grid bind this datatable to gridview